# Hide tables without display:none for Gmail emails

Tags: css, gmail, html-email, email-templates

I'm doing a product email and It looks very bad in gmail.

My code:

```
<tr id="PART1">
  <td  align="left">
    <table class="deviceWidth">
       <tr>
         <td colspan="2"  align="left">
            <img src="logo.gif" style="display:block" border="0"/>
         </td>
         <td id="TdIwantToHide" class="displayAction">Lorem ipsum</td>
      </tr>
     </table>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr id="PART2" class="deviceBlock">
   <td>
       <table class="deviceWidth">
          <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          </tr>
       </table>
   </td>
</tr>
```

CSS:
 .displayAction { display:block!important; }
         .deviceBlock { display:none!important; }

I also test removing the display and changed it to

```
line-height:0px;
font-size:0px;
height:0px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
```

because I see this fix in some websites and people said that make it work but it doesn't work. I can see both

Someone knows the way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can not effectively *hide* an element in Gmail but you can *zero it out*.

The trick is to leverage the difference between Gmail and other email clients.  This difference is the fact that Gmail will not read or render any styling other than inline styles.  Any CSS written within `<style></style>` tags will be ignored.

This is the case only for Gmail so we can use this difference to our advantage by setting the inline styling of the element we wish to hide to zero values, and in the `<style></style>` block we set the appropriate values for the element so all clients OTHER than Gmail will render the element appropriately.

```
<style>
*[class=mobile] {
    display:none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:600px) { 
    *[class=mobile] {
        display:block !important;
        width:auto !important;
        max-height:inherit !important;
        overflow:visible !important;
        float:none !important;
    }

    *[class="block"] {
        display:block !important;
        padding:5px;
    }
}
</style>

<!--[if !mso]><!-->
<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
    <tr>
        <td class="mobile" style="width:0;max-height:0;overflow: hidden;">
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/150x150" alt="" border=0 width="100%" style="display:block;" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

*The addition of the `mso` code in the example below is for the added support of Outlook.*

Answer (score 1):

Ah, well the problem is, gmail will strip any style tag in an email, which is why all html-emails need most styling to be done in-line.

Are you looking to hide content just on gmail, or on all desktop clients? As far as i know there's no way to conditionally target gmail.

(replying to comment below:)

You'll need to set `<td id="TdIwantToHide" class="displayAction" style="display:none;">` then, and in your media query show it again with `@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) { td[id="TdIwantToHide"] { display:block !important; } }` in your style tag.

Comment: I need to hide it in all desktop clients and I'm trying to find the way that works in all of them. But I'm very surprise to see that in gmail looks so bad.

Answer (score 1):

Try using      'visibility: hidden' and 'display: none' both along with your

```
    'line-height:0px;
     font-size:0px;
      height:0px;
      margin:0;
      padding:0;'
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `display:none; display:none !important;`.

The `display:none !important;` works in Gmail. The `display:none;` takes care of Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail does not support the inline display property if the value is set to “none.”
    `style=“display:none”`
Each of the other values for the display property are supported.
It’s important to note that Gmail does support the inline display property if the value is set to “none !important;” as below.
    `style=“display:none !important;”`